# multiple condition -if else in Macros based on search commands

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test2()
r = ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("$M2:$M" & r & " ").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""14 5415 Ruggge"",K2)),""PAD-LAPTOP"",""Yes"")"

End Sub
```

I had used this command in order to use multiple conditions. how can i use else condition in this command?

Comment: `IF` has the `ELSE` operating as the third parameter `=IF(condition, do_this, else_do_this)` - your question is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to edit your question. Otherwise people will minus it lowering your rating (like somebody did already). It is not so clear what you are trying to do, but to iterate through range and output certain value to its Offset is something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test2()

Dim cell
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("K1:K" & lRow)
    If cell.Value = "apple" Then
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "PAD-LAPTOP"
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Yes"
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know the exact cell value thats why used the command (ISNUMBER(SEARCH is any other way

Comment: @Priyankavivek what do you mean "you don't know exact cell value"? Your data should have some parameters in order to be compared to something. What is your data? Numbers, text etc?

Comment: combination of number and text,if number or text available it should be laptop or desktop i should mention

Comment: @Priyankavivek you need to specify your pattern. Is it always like this:  "nn nnnn ccccc"? Also if it is Desktop, why do you have Yes "if it is not true"?

Comment: Make your question clear. Specify your pattern. What is you combination of text and data... In what case it should be Desktop, in what case it should be Laptop... It is really hard to guess what your data looks like to write correct IF, ELSE statement

Comment: i have series number of model name which can be identified only serial number,where i have used the command search  and it is working fine but to check with multiple serial number some might not be desktop or laptop ,those columns i need to specify as "yes and how to proceed with else condition in this script which i have done"

Comment: kindly  help me on this kindly share your gmail ,priyaross94@gmail.com

Comment: if i  have for eg abc then it should be laptop,abc1 -->laptop,abcd2-->desktop,the model changes so i need to give condition like this